# How can i deserialize Google News Sitemap Feed c#

Tags: c#, xml, rss, sitemap

I have a Google News Sitemap Feed but i can't deserialize xml on c# list collection.

I want get first 50 items from my feed.

What can i do for this ? Any idea ? Thanks

My xml sample is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://www.hellenicshippingnews.com/wp-content/plugins/xml-sitemap-feed/includes/xsl/sitemap-news.xsl?ver=4.7.3"?>
<!-- generated-on="2016-11-07T12:40:55+00:00" -->
<!-- generator="XML & Google News Sitemap Feed plugin for WordPress" -->
<!-- generator-url="http://status301.net/wordpress-plugins/xml-sitemap-feed/" -->
<!-- generator-version="4.7.3" -->
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9" 
xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
    http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd
    http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9
    http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9/sitemap-news.xsd
    http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1
    http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1/sitemap-image.xsd">
<url>
    <loc>http://www.hellenicshippingnews.com/odc-to-convert-fifth-greek-vessel-olympic-target/</loc>
    <news:news>
        <news:publication>
            <news:name>Hellenic Shipping News Worldwide</news:name>
            <news:language>en</news:language>
        </news:publication>
        <news:publication_date>2016-11-07T10:00:57+00:00</news:publication_date>
        <news:title>ODC to convert fifth Greek vessel Olympic Target</news:title>
        <news:keywords>Hellenic Shipping News, ΒunkerportsnewsΠρώτηΣελιδα, Πρώτη σελιδα</news:keywords>
    </news:news>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>http://www.hellenicshippingnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/double-hulled_oil_tanker.jpg</image:loc>
        <image:title><![CDATA[double-hulled_oil_tanker]]></image:title>
    </image:image>
</url>
</urlset>
```

I try with this c# code but nothing happened:

```
XDocument feedXML = XDocument.Load("http://www.hellenicshippingnews.com/sitemap-news.xml");

        var feeds = from feed in feedXML.Descendants("url")
                    select new
                    {
                        Title = feed.Element("loc").Value,
                        Link = feed.Element("news:title").Value,
                        Description = feed.Element("news:keywords").Value
                    };
```

Comment: What do you mean by *nothing happened*? Please, be more specific. Is a runtime exception thrown? Does the LINQ yield an empty result?

Comment: doesn't find somethind on .Descendants("url")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting about the namespaces (see those `xmlns` attributes around `urlset` root element).

Also, you should use [Descendants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360635(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead of [Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element(v=vs.110).aspx)

*See notes in bold below:*

Per documentation, `Element`:

> Gets the first (in document order) **child element** with the specified XName.

And, `Descendants`:

> Returns a collection of the **descendant elements** for this document or element, in document order.

A child element is considered a direct inner node of the parent element. `title` and `keywords` aren't child nodes of `url`, so you should use `Descendants` method to search deeper in the node hierarchy.

```
string ns = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
string news_ns = "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9";
var feeds = from feed in feedXML.Descendants(String.Format("{{{0}}}{1}", ns, "url"))
            select new
            {
                Title = feed.Element(String.Format("{{{0}}}{1}", ns, "loc")).Value,
                Link = feed.Descendants(String.Format("{{{0}}}{1}", news_ns, "title")).Single().Value,
                Description = feed.Descendants(String.Format("{{{0}}}{1}", news_ns, "keywords")).Single().Value
            };
```

Comment: Wow !! Thanks , I can't understand your code perfectly but it's working !!!
how can i get and image:loc value ??

Comment: @G.Mich For the `publication_date` just follow the same pattern of `title` and `keywords`. For `image:title` you would need to locate the `image` namespace, which is `http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1` **(Look at the `urlset` element, you can find all the namespaces there)**. You'll then follow the same pattern as `title` and `keyword`, but you'd pass a different namespace. In your case, `image_ns`.